# how convert list of int to list of tuples

Tags: python

I want to convert a list like this

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

to

```
l2 = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]
```

because want to loop

```
for x,y in l2:
    draw_thing(x,y)
```

Comment: This comes up a lot. Here the more general case for groups of N: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n/1625043#1625043

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on Nick D's answer:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> t = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> for a, b in izip(*[iter(t)]*2):
...     print a, b
...
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
>>> for a, b, c in izip(*[iter(t)]*3):
...     print a, b, c
...
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
>>> for a, b, c, d in izip(*[iter(t)]*4):
...     print a, b, c, d
...
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
>>> for a, b, c, d, e, f in izip(*[iter(t)]*6):
...     print a, b, c, d, e, f
...
1 2 3 4 5 6
7 8 9 10 11 12
>>>
```

Not quite as readable, but it shows a compact way to get any size tuple you want.

Answer (score 10):

One *good* way is:

```
from itertools import izip
it = iter([1, 2, 3, 4])
for x, y in izip(it, it):
    print x, y
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
>>>
```

Comment: Never thought of using a single iterator twice to zip... that's slick.  For the finishing touch you'd want to use `from itertools import izip` to avoid making an extra copy.

Comment: One more change: `zip(*[iter(the_list)]*2)` (or `*3` for 3-tuples, etc).

Answer (score 5):

Kind of easy with python's slicing operator:

```
l2 = zip(l1[0::2], l1[1::2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at grouper function from [itertools docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

In your case use it like this:

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for (x, y) in grouper(2, l1):
    draw_thing(x, y)
```

Comment: Essentially just a long-hand version of what Steve Losh wrote.

Comment: Right, I didn't saw his answer. But it's not exactly the same. This version may be usefull, when lenght of the list isn't dividable by amount of items you want to process in the loop.

Comment: +1 I like this version, it's clearer, works with other lengths as you said, and is already on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
l2 = []
for y in range(0, len(l1), 2):
    l2.append((l1[y], l1[y+1]))
```

I'm not doing any checks to make sure l1 has an even number of entries and such-like.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution

```
l2 = [(l1[i], l1[i+1]) for i in xrange(0,len(l1),2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to construct a new list.  You can just iterate over the list by steps of 2 instead of 1.  I use `len(L) - 1` as the upper-bound so you ensure that you don't try to access past the end of the list.

```
for i in range(0, len(L) - 1, 2):
    draw_thing(L[i], L[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 it = iter(list)
 newlist = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(it, it)]
```

Comment: You're iterating over (and unpacking) the tuples returned by `zip` to create a list of identical tuples. In Python 2 the list comprehension is superfluous, and in Python 3 you can just call `list`.

Answer (score -3):

What's wrong with just accessing the correct index and incrementing?
`for (int i=0;i<myList.Length;i++)
{
  draw_thing(myList[i],myList[++i]);
}`

Oops - sorry, in C# mode. I'm sure you get the idea.

Comment: He asked for the answer in Python :P

Comment: didnt you know? everything in python has to be in 1 line. even if that line is 300 chars long

Comment: list indexes are dirty and distasteful