# Way to iterate two items at a time in a list?

Tags: python, maya

I am wondering if there is a better way to iterate two items at a time in a list. I work with Maya a lot, and one of its commands (listConnections) returns a list of alternating values. The list will look like [connectionDestination, connectionSource, connectionDestination, connectionSource]. To do anything with this list, I would ideally like to do something similar to:

```
for destination, source in cmds.listConnections():
    print source, destination
```

You could, of course just iterate every other item in the list using [::2] and enumerate and source would be the index+1, but then you have to add in extra checks for odd numbered lists and stuff.

The closest thing I have come up with so far is:

```
from itertools import izip
connections = cmds.listConnections()
for destination, source in izip(connections[::2], connections[1::2]):
    print source, destination
```

This isn't super important, as I already have ways of doing what I want. This just seems like one of those things that there should be a better way of doing it.

Comment: take a look at this post, maybe it'll help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n

Comment: also, what you have seems like a good way to do it. does it work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the following method for grouping items from an iterable, taken from the documentation for [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
connections = cmds.listConnections()
for destination, source in zip(*[iter(connections)]*2):
    print source, destination
```

Or for a more readable version, use the [grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) from the itertools documentation:

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: Oh, wow.  It took me a moment to figure out how `grouper()` works.  We build the `args` list so that all the args are references to a single iterator; thus, when `itertools.izip_longest()` tries to pull a value from each sequence, it is really pulling the next value from the same iterator!  Elegant and efficient!

Answer (score 3):

All, 
Great question & answer. I'd like to provide another solution that should compliment Andrew Clark's answer (props for using itertools!). His answer returns each value once like this:

`iterable = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,...]
n = 2
grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None) 
--> [(0, 1), (2, 3), (3, 4), (5, 6),...]`

In the code below each value will appear in n sub-sequences. Like this:

```
def moving_window(n, iterable):
  start, stop = 0, n
  while stop <= len(iterable):
      yield iterable[start:stop]
      start += 1
      stop += 1
```

`--> [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4),...]`

A common application for this type of 'moving window' or 'kernel' is moving averages in the sciences and finance.

Also note that the yield statement allows each sub-sequence to be created as it's needed and not stored in memory.

Answer (score 0):

why not just use `range` with the `step=2`?

```py
for i in range(0, len(connections)):
  source, destination = connections[i:i + 2]
  print source, destination
```

you can make a generic function out of it like:

```py
def tuples(iterable, arity):
  return [iterable[i:i+arity] for i in range(0, len(iterable), arity)]
```

Comment: Today I learned what the word arity means.  Great variable name.