# How to move items from a list into a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to move items from a list into a dictionary but I get the following error:

> 'int' object is not subscriptable

Here is my code:

```
l_s = ['one', 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3, 'four', 4, 'five', 5, 'six', 6]
d = {}

for line in l_s:
    if line[0] in d:
        d[line[0]].append(line[1])
    else:
        d[line[0]] = [line[1]]

print(d)
```

How would I go about changing it?

Comment: What language are you coding in?

Comment: Remove the slices `[0]` and `[1]`.  What is your desired output?

Comment: @danny30. any clarification on what you require? if one of the answers below helped, feel free to accept one (tick on left) so that other users can see a tested solution.

Answer (score 1):

*Why do you get an error?*

In Python, that error typically means "You can't slice this object."  Strings, lists, tuples, etc are sliceable, but integers are not.  The error is raised during iteration as it comes across an integer.

*Options*

Depending on what results you want, here are some options to try:

1. Pre-process your input, e.g. a list of pairs `[('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5), ('six', 6)]`.
2. Remove the incompatible indices.
3. Use a tool to build a dictionary from pairs, e.g. [`pip install more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.sliced).

*Solution*

I suspect you want results similar to option 3:

```
import more_itertools as mit


lst = ['one', 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3, 'four', 4, 'five', 5, 'six', 6]
{k: v for k, v in mit.sliced(lst, 2)}
# {'five': 5, 'four': 4, 'one': 1, 'six': 6, 'three': 3, 'two': 2}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will go back and work on this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

Using [Way to iterate two items at a time in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350342/way-to-iterate-two-items-at-a-time-in-a-list) and dictionary comprehension:

```
>> l_s = ['one', 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3, 'four', 4, 'five', 5, 'six', 6]
>>> {k:v for k, v in zip(*[iter(l_s)]*2)}
{'six': 6, 'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `collections.defaultdict`, a subclass of `dict`. This sets the default value for *any* key to an empty list and allows you to easily append. Below is a guess of what you are looking for:

```
from collections import defaultdict

l_s = ['one', 1, 'two', 2, 'three', 3, 'four', 4, 'five', 5, 'six', 6]

d = defaultdict(list)

for txt, num in zip(l_s[::2], l_s[1::2]):
    d[txt].append(num)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {'five': [5],
#              'four': [4],
#              'one': [1],
#              'six': [6],
#              'three': [3],
#              'two': [2]})
```

Comment: I did some research and found the collections mod. I will apply that in the furture. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @danny30, that's great. feel free to upvote or accept (tick on left) so others know this works.