# How to split a string using an empty separator in Python

Tags: python, string, split

What is a good way to do `some_string.split('')` in python? This syntax gives an error:

```
a = '1111'
a.split('')

ValueError: empty separator
```

I would like to obtain:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Comment: Do you really need to do that? Most of the time you can treat a string in the same way you treat a list anyway.

Comment: I tried to do that and it gave this error, so I thought it would be nice to include here as a question

Comment: You might also find this interesting - [Alternative way to split a list into groups of n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1624883/12892).

Comment: @sqpc: No, it would not give "this error", so you didn't try that. Did you try to just do nothing? Not split it at all?

Comment: @sgpc: You aren't reading the comments very carefully. Did you try to do NOTHING AT ALL? That's what arshaji suggest. Do NOT split it. AT ALL. What happens then?

Comment: @LennartRegebro thank you for your answer. I was just trying to transform a string like: `a = '1111\n1100\n1001\n0111'` in a 2D-array, doing: `np.array([i.split('') for i in a.split('\n')], dtype=int)`, this was the origin of the question

Comment: @sgpc: OK. And what happens if you don't `.split()` `i`?

Comment: @LennartRegebro in this case it returns: `array([1111, 1100, 1001,  111])`

Comment: Ah, so there's implicit conversion to integers as well. Yeah, then you need `list(i)`.

Comment: @arshajii contrary to your "most of the time ",'str' object does not support item assignment. This fill the need.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Use [`list()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list):

```
>>> list('1111')
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Alternatively, you can use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) (Python 2.7 only):

```
>>> map(None, '1111')
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Time differences:

```
$ python -m timeit "list('1111')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.483 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "map(None, '1111')"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.431 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 13):

One can cast strings to list directly

```
>>> list('1111')
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

or using list comprehensions

```
>>> [i for i in '1111']
['1', '1', '1', '1']
```

second way can be useful if one wants to split strings for substrings more than 1 symbol length

```
>>> some_string = '12345'
>>> [some_string[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(some_string), 2)]
['12', '34', '5']
```

Answer (score 5):

Strings are iterables and can be indexed, hence you don't really need to split it at all:

```
>>> for char in '11111':
...   print char
... 
1
1
1
1
1
>>> '11111'[4]
'1'
```

You can "split" it with a call to list, but it doesn't make much difference:

```
>>> for char in list('11111'):
...   print char
... 
1
1
1
1
1
>>> list('11111')[4]
'1'
```

So you only need to do this if your code explicitly expects a list. For example:

```
>>> list('11111').append('2')
>>> l = list('11111')
>>> l.append(2)
>>> l
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 2]
```

This doesn't work with a straight string:

```
>>> l.append('2')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

In that case you would need:

```
>>> l += '2'
>>> l
'111112'
```

Answer (score 3):

## Method #1:

```
s="Amalraj"
l=[i for i in s]
print(l)
```

### Output:

```
['A', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'r', 'a', 'j']
```

## Method #2:

```
s="Amalraj"
l=list(s)
print(l)
```

### Output:

```
['A', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'r', 'a', 'j']
```

## Method #3:

```
import re; # importing regular expression module
s="Amalraj"
l=re.findall('.',s)
print(l)
```

### Output:

```
['A', 'm', 'a', 'l', 'r', 'a', 'j']
```

Answer (score 2):

If like me you arrived here to split in packets and not char by char, I made this :

```py
>>> n=2
>>> str='423346396677674A446E6838436E304164334A30427874784467567863334942446E41424E413D3D'
>>> [ str[byte:byte+n] for byte in range(0,len(str)) if byte % n == 0 ]
['42', '33', '46', '39', '66', '77', '67', '4A', '44', '6E', '68', '38', '43', '6E', '30', '41', '64', '33', '4A', '30', '42', '78', '74', '78', '44', '67', '56', '78', '63', '33', '49', '42', '44', '6E', '41', '42', '4E', '41', '3D', '3D']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even omit the list() call altogether, with a combination of map + lambda fn and then use unpacking.

```
>>> s = "efgvdfbdb"
>>> [* map(lambda x: x, s) ]
['e', 'f', 'g', 'v', 'd', 'f', 'b', 'd', 'b']
```