# How to find subimage using the PIL library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to find the sub-image from large image using PIL library. I also want to know the coordinates where it is found ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Anyway - if you want something like face detection and so on - forget about PIL (it is not designed for this kind of job) and look for OpenCV.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear? give a few lines of code of what you already did, what data format your image has etc.

Comment: i haven't started coding yet. I want the subimage from large image. for ex. we have screen shot of any player. we have seekbar image. now i want to find the location of seekbar using PIL.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
image = cv2.imread("Large.png")
template = cv2.imread("small.png")
result = cv2.matchTemplate(image,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
print np.unravel_index(result.argmax(),result.shape)
```

This works fine and in efficient way for me.

Answer (score 10):

I managed to do this only using PIL.

Some caveats:

1. This is a pixel perfect search. It simply looks for matching RGB pixels.
2. For simplicity I remove the alpha/transparency channel. I'm only looking for RGB pixels.
3. This code loads the entire subimage pixel array into memory, while keeping the large image out of memory. On my system Python maintained a ~26 MiB memory footprint for a tiny 40x30 subimage searching through a 1920x1200 screenshot.
4. This simple example isn't very efficient, but increasing efficiency will add complexity. Here I'm keeping things straight forward and easy to understand.
5. This example works on Windows and OSX. Not tested on Linux. It takes a screenshot of the primary display only (for multi monitor setups).

Here's the code:

```
import os
from itertools import izip

from PIL import Image, ImageGrab


def iter_rows(pil_image):
    """Yield tuple of pixels for each row in the image.

    From:
    http://stackoverflow.com/a/1625023/1198943

    :param PIL.Image.Image pil_image: Image to read from.

    :return: Yields rows.
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    iterator = izip(*(iter(pil_image.getdata()),) * pil_image.width)
    for row in iterator:
        yield row


def find_subimage(large_image, subimg_path):
    """Find subimg coords in large_image. Strip transparency for simplicity.

    :param PIL.Image.Image large_image: Screen shot to search through.
    :param str subimg_path: Path to subimage file.

    :return: X and Y coordinates of top-left corner of subimage.
    :rtype: tuple
    """
    # Load subimage into memory.
    with Image.open(subimg_path) as rgba, rgba.convert(mode='RGB') as subimg:
        si_pixels = list(subimg.getdata())
        si_width = subimg.width
        si_height = subimg.height
    si_first_row = tuple(si_pixels[:si_width])
    si_first_row_set = set(si_first_row)  # To speed up the search.
    si_first_pixel = si_first_row[0]

    # Look for first row in large_image, then crop and compare pixel arrays.
    for y_pos, row in enumerate(iter_rows(large_image)):
        if si_first_row_set - set(row):
            continue  # Some pixels not found.
        for x_pos in range(large_image.width - si_width + 1):
            if row[x_pos] != si_first_pixel:
                continue  # Pixel does not match.
            if row[x_pos:x_pos + si_width] != si_first_row:
                continue  # First row does not match.
            box = x_pos, y_pos, x_pos + si_width, y_pos + si_height
            with large_image.crop(box) as cropped:
                if list(cropped.getdata()) == si_pixels:
                    # We found our match!
                    return x_pos, y_pos


def find(subimg_path):
    """Take a screenshot and find the subimage within it.

    :param str subimg_path: Path to subimage file.
    """
    assert os.path.isfile(subimg_path)

    # Take screenshot.
    with ImageGrab.grab() as rgba, rgba.convert(mode='RGB') as screenshot:
        print find_subimage(screenshot, subimg_path)
```

Speed:

```
$ python -m timeit -n1 -s "from tests.screenshot import find" "find('subimg.png')"
(429, 361)
(465, 388)
(536, 426)
1 loops, best of 3: 316 msec per loop
```

While running the above command I moved the window containing the subimage diagonally as `timeit` was running.

Comment: while doing it in pure python is POSSIBLE, it is very slow compared to a C-based implementation ^^ still, +1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to perform *object detection*, probably via *template matching*. It's not a trivial problem unless you're looking for an exact pixel-by-pixel match, and PIL is not meant to do this sort of thing.

Jan is right that you should try OpenCV. It's a robust computer vision library with good Python bindings.

Here's a nice short example in Python that draws a rectangle around the matched region:
https://github.com/jungilhan/Tutorial/blob/master/OpenCV/templateMatching.py

Answer (score 0):

[pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze) is an alternative, for example:

```
big = PIL.Image.open("big.bmp");
small = PIL.Image.open("small.bmp");
locations = pyscreeze.locateAll(small, big);
```

returns a list like

```
((x,y),(x,y),(x,y))
```

positions :) for example, lets say you're playing the game [Swords & Souls: Neverseen](https://store.steampowered.com/app/679900/Swords__Souls_Neverseen/)
 and you want to practice the distance-skill programmatically
[image]

first save an image of the bullseye red pixels and save it as a bmp (it's IMPORTANT that you use a lossless image format, like png or bmp, not a lossy format like jpg):

[image]

and load it like

```
Bullseye = PIL.Image.open("bullseye.bmp")
```

then get the position of the game window:

```
windowPosition = win32gui.GetWindowRect(
        win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Swords & Souls Neverseen"))
```

then take a screenshot of the game:

```
image = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(windowPosition)
```

then locate all the bullseyes:

```
locations = pyscreeze.locateAll(bullseye, image)
```

then click on all the bullseyes:

```
        for location in locations:
            # calculate absolute screen x/y from the game's x/y
            x = location[0] + windowPosition[0]
            y = location[1] + windowPosition[1]
            pyautogui.click(x], y)
```

in short:

```
import PIL
import win32gui
import pyautogui as pyautogui
import pyscreeze

Bullseye = PIL.Image.open("bullseye.bmp")
windowPosition = win32gui.GetWindowRect(
        win32gui.FindWindow(None, "Swords & Souls Neverseen"))
while True:
    image = PIL.ImageGrab.grab(windowPosition)
    locations = pyscreeze.locateAll(bullseye, image)
    for location in locations:
        x = location[0] + windowPosition[0]
        y = location[1] + windowPosition[1]
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

and your python script should practice distance skills till the end of time (-:

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to object detection in images topic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).