# How to Split Python list every Nth element

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, split

What I am trying to do is pretty simple, but I couldn't find how to do it.

- Starting with 1st element, put every 4th element into a new list.
- Repeat with the 2nd, 3rd, and 4th elements.

From:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b']
```

To:

```
list1 = ['1', '5', '9']
list2 = ['2', '6', 'a']
list3 = ['3', '7', 'b']
list4 = ['4', '9']
```

In other words, I need to know how to:

- Get the Nth element from a list (in a loop)
- Store it in new arrays
- Repeat

Comment: Don't generate new variables. Store your lists in a parent list instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The specific solution is to use slicing with a stride:

```
source = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b']
list1 = source[::4]
list2 = source[1::4]
list3 = source[2::4]
list4 = source[3::4]
```

`source[::4]` takes every 4th element, starting at index 0; the other slices only alter the starting index.

The *generic* solution is to use a loop to do the slicing, and store the result in an outer list; a list comprehension can do that nicely:

```
def slice_per(source, step):
    return [source[i::step] for i in range(step)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> source = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b']
>>> source[::4]
['1', '5', '9']
>>> source[1::4]
['2', '6', 'a']
>>> def slice_per(source, step):
...     return [source[i::step] for i in range(step)]
... 
>>> slice_per(source, 4)
[['1', '5', '9'], ['2', '6', 'a'], ['3', '7', 'b'], ['4', '8']]
>>> slice_per(source, 3)
[['1', '4', '7', 'a'], ['2', '5', '8', 'b'], ['3', '6', '9']]
```

Comment: Why not make it a generator? It will handle the infinite case too then.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks: You'd have to make `n` `islice` iterators then.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks: which means you'd have to tee off the input iterable, and that could potentially become very expensive, memory wise.

Comment: @EdgarKlerks: it appears you were thinking of [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/312443)..

Comment: You are right, I didn't read the original question too well. My fault.

Comment: Do note that **this will change the order of the items in the original list**. If you want `[[0, 1, 2],  [3, 4, 5]]` style output, this will not work. (Yes, for this question the above answer is correct, but I was looking for this kind of output and stumbled upon this on google.) Ended up using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624988) instead.

Comment: @zertap the order is not altered, we select every 4th element *in order*. What you want is something different, you want to take fixed-size chunks, see [What is the most "pythonic" way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287).

Answer (score 4):

The numbered names are a bad idea, and you shouldn't name your own variable `list` (it shadows the built-in), but in general you can do something like:

```
>>> startlist = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b']
>>> n = 4
>>> endlist = [[] for _ in range(n)]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(startlist):
    endlist[index % n].append(item)


>>> endlist
[['1', '5', '9'], ['2', '6', 'a'], ['3', '7', 'b'], ['4', '8']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']
s = []
n = 3
for x in range(n):
    s.append(lst[x::n])
    print(s)
```

Comment: An explanation is required for such an answer even if the explanation is one line long and consists roughly of one sentence. Consider updating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

```
list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b']
lists = []
list_temp = []

for _, __ in enumerate(list, 1):
  list_temp.append(__)
  if _ % 3 == 0 or _ == len(list):
    lists.append(list_temp)
    list_temp = []
```

This will append the chunks in a temporary list and append the temporary list to our final list every time the index divided by the desired list length has no remainders.

It’s more a mathematical approach than a pythonic one :)