# Python: reading N number from file, M at time

Tags: python, file, io

My file is this one:

```
14
3
21
37
48
12
4
6
22
4
```

How can I read M number at time? for example 4 at time. Is it necessary to use two *for* loops?

My goal is to create (N/M)+1 lists with M numbers inside every lists, except the final list (it's the reminder of division N/M)

Comment: Have you tried implementing it with two `for` loops?  That would be a good place to start, and if you have trouble, you can ask for help.

Comment: I edited my answer. Pls check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use python list `slice` operator to fetch the number of required elements from a file by reading a file using `readlines()` where each element of list will be one line of file.

```
with open("filename") as myfile:
    firstNtoMlines = myfile.readlines()[N:N+M] # the interval you want to read
    print firstNtoMlines
```

Comment: I've tried with this solution. I've put it into a while cycle

Comment: yes, it should work, my code is in a post above this one

Answer (score 0):

Use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice),

```
import itertools 
import math

filename = 'test.dat'
N = 9
M = 4

num_rest_lines = N
nrof_lists = int(math.ceil(N*1.0/M))

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(nrof_lists):
        num_lines = min(num_rest_lines, M)
        lines_gen =  itertools.islice(f, num_lines)

        l = [int(line.rstrip()) for line in lines_gen]
        num_rest_lines = num_rest_lines - M

        print(l)    
        # Output
        [14, 3, 21, 37]
        [48, 12, 4, 6]
        [22]
```

---

**Previous answer**: Iterate over a file (`N` lines) in chunks (every `M` lines), forming a list of `N/M+1` lists.

```
import itertools 

def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    """iterate in chunks"""
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

# Test
filename = 'test.dat'
m = 4
fillvalue = '0'

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lists = [[int(item.rstrip()) for item in chuck] for chuck in grouper(f, m, fillvalue=fillvalue)]
    print(lists)
    # Output
    [[14, 3, 21, 37], [48, 12, 4, 6], [22, 4, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: i don't know why izip_longest method doesn't appear when i import itertools. I use Anaconda. i can't call it

Comment: i type "from itertools import..." but Eclispe don't found izip_method. No error, just this

Comment: @LorenzoVannucchi, if import a moduly by `from itertools import izip_longest`, this line `itertools.izip_longest` should be replaced with izip_longest`.

Answer (score 0):

Now my code is this one:

```
N = 4
M = 0

while (M < 633):
    with open("/Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/X","r") as myFile:
        res = myFile.readlines()[M:N]
        print(res)
    M+=4
    N+=4
```

so, It should work. My file's got 633 numbers

Answer (score -1):

This has been asked before.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
izip_longest(*(iter(yourlist),) * yourgroupsize)
```

For the case of grouping lines in a file into lists of size 4:

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    res = izip_longest(*(iter(f)),) * 4)
    print res
```

[Alternative way to split a list into groups of n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n)