# Create group of three lines with Python

Tags: python, grouping

I have a text file with many lines like this:

```
aDB8786793440
bDB8978963432
cDB9898908345
dDB8908908454
eDB9083459089
fDB9082390843
gDB9083490345
```

I need to create groups of three, final format is less relevant as long as i can access the each group.

Desired output:

```py
# something like this
group_1 = ["aDB8786793440", "bDB8978963432", "cDB9898908345"]
group_2 = ["dDB8908908454", "eDB9083459089", "fDB9082390843"]

# or like this
groups = [["aDB8786793440", "bDB8978963432", "cDB9898908345"], ["dDB8908908454", "eDB9083459089", "fDB9082390843"]]
```

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: What if the number of items isn't a multiple of 3?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624883/alternative-way-to-split-a-list-into-groups-of-n

Comment: Python 3.12: [itertools.batched](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.batched), see [this Q&A for this and more solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75981543/10513287)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope my code helps. It will create groups of 3 and will then have a final group with any remainders.

```
groups = []

with open('text') as f:
    f = f.readlines()

for x in range(0,len(f),3):
    groups.append(f[x:3+x])

print(groups)
```